# How to display annotations besides core editor of visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sdk, annotations, editor

I need to programmatically create an annotation bar which shows line by line information besides text/source-code files. The solution needs to work for both, Visual Studio 2008 and 2010. I don't want to lose any feature of the core editor like syntax highlighting and so on. Do I need to implement a custom editor or is there any simpler way around?

The way I am currently going is to create a custom editor component containing a Windows.Forms.SplitContainer having a custom component on the left and a RichTextBox as the editor on the right. But this solution only shows non highlighted text.

I imagine placing an instance of the core editor into the second pane of the SplitContainer but have no idea if thats possible or how to get there.

BTW I am aiming for a C# solution.

Comment: I am currently dissecting AnkhSvn as they are doing a very similar thing with SVN blame information. However even if their editor seems to be rich featured, it does not provide all features of the core editor: Files are write protected, no split view support, limited context menu features - as far as my current observations go.

Comment: I would like to achieve the same thing. Is this even possible? I would like to do it for Visual Studio 2017.